# The backup destination specified by the remote shared folder does not exist

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, webdav, windows-server-backup

I have a webdav share which I mount to my windows 2008 r2 server via webdav (desktop experience feature).

Is it possible to backup to this? I get the error:

Windows server backu is unable to access the remote shared folder.

The backup destination specified by the remote shared folder does not exist.

I can't assign permissions to the share as it's a webdav folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't assign permissions to the share as it's a webdav folder.

Actually, you should be able to assign permissions the server side, at least a login. There may even be some default privileges being used. You need to provide more information about the server you're trying to connect to? Is this a service you have access to. Is it configured to use LDAP? Is it a password-less setup? Can you access the url from the browser?

You should be able to map the webdav location as a network drive in explorer:

net use z: https://servername/webdav /PERSISTENT:YES /USER:user password

Then, use robocopy to transfer the source to the destination:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

This will help the transfer complete successfully over network connections.

Keeping a webdav folder mapped as a drive also has it's limitations. You need to tweak the webclient parameters to handle large file transfers. Here are a few important notes I've accumulated over time for trouble shooting webdav connections on Windows Server 2008:

**System error 1397 has occurred. Mutual Authentication failed. The server's password is out of date at the domain controller.**

You need to apply this patch: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2489177

**Failed to copy, (The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved)**

FileSizeLimitInBytes is set to 5000000 which limits your download so just set it to maximum! (this is client side btw on windows 7)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters

- Right click on the FileSizeLimitInBytes and click Modify
- Click on Decimal
- In the Value data box, type 4294967295, and then click OK. Note this sets the maximum you can download from the Webdav to 4 gig at one time, I haven?t figured out how to make it unlimited so if you want to download more you need to split it up.
- Open ControlPanel->Administrative Toools->Services and restart the 'WebClient' service

**Error 0x80070079: The semaphore timeout period has expired**

This is apparently a common issue for many ppl with windows 7 when working with webdav/sharepoint over https/ssl:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistanetworking/thread/c3fc9f5d-c073-4a9f-bb3d-b7bb8f893f78/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/1e654537-fd40-4b89-ac1c-f66bdd9fcd2e

http://forums.iis.net/p/1182933/2001427.aspx